# Elements of finite order in $\mathbb Z.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm doing an exercise in my abstract algebra book. According to it the solution to "Find all elements of finite order in $\mathbb{Z}$" is 
$
\{0, 1, -1\}.$ Since $\mathbb{Z}$ includes $0$, I assume the group operation is +. (The other exercises with $\mathbb{Q}^*$ and $\mathbb{R}^*$ specifically exclude $0$.)

Why is this solution true? I get $0$, since $0^0=0$ but there is no $k$ for which $1^k =1*k = 0$ but not $5*k=0$ and neither for $-1$.

Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm on mobile.

[image: Exercise]
[image: Solution]

Comment: You'll need to cite the problem verbatim.  As it stands, it is either written wrongly or the problem itself is nonsense.

Comment: @Randall thanks for your reply, I added an image of the problem.

Comment: Yeah the problem is wrong

Comment: The solution is wrong. If the operation is addition then the identity element is $0$ and you want to find out which elements $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ have a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $na=0$. An it is obvious that only the identity element $0$ has such an $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of confusion

Comment: The asserted answer is flat-out wrong.

Comment: @Mark but isn't every a*0=0 shouldn't all elements have order 0? Edit: nevermind 0 is not natural I assume

Comment: No, the number $n$ I talked about must be a natural number. $0$ is not a natural number so you can't take $n=0$.

Comment: Perhaps the author forgot to type `\item` after the $0$, and in stead meant to write
$$\text{(a)}\ 0;\ \text{(b)}\ 1,-1;\ \text{(c)}\ 1,-1.$$

Comment: ^Absolutely what happened.  Good detective work!

Comment: Could you put in the question which book is? The purpose is to avoid headaches to other future readers and make this thread easily searchable.